# is there anything exist to convert xml -> yaml directly?

Tags: python, xml, tags, yaml

is there any library or way exist from which I can convert my xml records to yaml format ?

Answer (score 4):

[This page](http://web.archive.org/web/20080804171718/http://yaml.kwiki.org/index.cgi?XmlYaml) has a pretty long discussion of the problem. It suggests a couple of Python libraries that could be used: [Gnosis](http://gnosis.cx/download/) and [generateDS](http://www.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/#generateDS.).

Comment: Thanks, @Patt, it looks like that whole wiki has gone down. I replaced the link with a Wayback Machine snapshot.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between XML and YAML is significant enough to warrant a redesign of the schema you are using to store your data. You should write a script to parse your XML records and output YAML formatted data.

There are some methods out there to convert any generic XML into YAML, but the results are far less usable than a method designed specifically for your schema.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to look at the [YAXML draft spec](http://yaml.org/xml.html), which describes how to represent YAML data structures in XML.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you are looking for a way to do this inside a script/program, or any Python method will do.

In the latter case, the `yq` and `xq` utilities can do this:

```
cat file.xml | xq . | yq -y .
```

They might also be reusable as libraries or at least reused code.

On OpenSUSE, they are available in the `python3-yq` package.

See https://github.com/mikefarah/yq for source and https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/ for documentation.

Comment: I wonder if anyone has link(s) to either mentioned tool? It looks like [`xq` is this?](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq)

Comment: Added package name for OpenSUSE, source and documentation links.