# Is there a conversion tool for XML to YAML?

Tags: xml, yaml, file-conversion, data-conversion

I have an XML file structure and I want to convert it to YAML file structure and probably also for the future use.

Could you please suggest/recommend me a conversion tool to convert XML to YAML?

Comment: see here maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943862/is-there-anything-exist-to-convert-xml-yaml-directly

There are a bunch of tools mentionned

Comment: You may want to check out [Data Transformer](https://geosystemsdev.com/products/data-transformer/) (disclaimer - I'm its developer). It converts between XML, YML, and other formats locally.

You can get it from the [Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/data-transformer/id1490843070) or the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/data-transformer/9p2xp6nt2pv2).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Editing this answer as I realize today when I wrote it, I had a little experience with YAML.

*YAML* stands for **Y**AML **A**in't **M**arkup **L**anguage. Having said that, XML (e**X**tensible **M**arkup **L**anguage) is. So theoretically, you would have feature limitations converting one to another (in this case XML to YAML..) although YAML, having experienced it while creating AWS Stacks, seems to be more "human" friendly in comparison to XML.

A) You *could* use an online tool *(although you must be careful. Your company policies might concern you about uploading software specs online)*:

- https://codebeautify.org/xml-to-yaml
- https://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-xml-csv
- https://www.browserling.com/tools/xml-to-yaml
- You could Google it - I'm positive you would find much more...

B) You *could* use a C# (.NET) to convert XML to YAML.

There are NuGet packages available providing you Serialization tools allow your app do that in the code. (See: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=yaml)

C) Worse case scenario - and I'm not liking my original idea: you *could* build an XSL file would help you to transform an XML file to literally any other text format (hypertext content). XSL Reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256069.aspx)